# Problema com namespace e include

Tags: php, classes, namespace, include

Bom dia. Tenho um webservice feito em slimPHP . Tenho uma classe que se chama `control`, e ele pertence ao namespace `controllers`, ela funciona normalmente sem problemas , mas surgiu a necessidade de importar um classe para manipulação de PDF , so que quando dou o include ele da erro , dizendo que não encontrou a classe solicitada. Alguém sabe o que pode ser ? Segue a classe.

```
<?php

 namespace controllers {

  include "fpdf/fpdf.php";


   class Control {

    //Atributo para banco de dados
    private $PDO;

    /*
      __construct
      Conectando ao banco de dados
     */

      function __construct() {
        $this->PDO = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=infoged', 'root', 
              '*******'); //ConexÃ£o
                  $this->PDO->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); //habilitando erros do PDO
    }

    public function PDF($romaneio) {
       $pdf =  new \fpdf\FPDF("P", "pt", "A4");
       $pdf->AddPage();
    }
  }
 }
```

Erro:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'fpdf\FPDF' not found in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\infoged\services\controllers\Control.php</b> on line
<b>142</b>
```

Inicio do arquivo `FPDF`

```
 define('FPDF_VERSION', '1.81');


class FPDF {

    protected $page;               // current page number
    protected $n;                  // current object number
    protected $offsets;            // array of object offsets
    protected $buffer;             // buffer holding in-memory PDF
    protected $pages;      
 .....
 }
```

Comment: Acredito que se você postar o erro que da, irá ajudar bastante jovem.

Comment: Beleza , postando!

Comment: É bem provável que o erro seja porquê você efetuou o `include` dentro do `namespace`, incluindo as classes FPDF no mesmo, enquanto você tenta acessar a classe no `namespace \fpdf`. Tente dar o `include` antes do `namespace`.

Comment: Quando dou o include antes do namespace ele me retorna esse erro.```<b>Fatal error</b>:  Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in```

Comment: O que possui dentro do arquivo fpdf.php? Poderia postar apenas a inicialização da classe neste arquivo por favor?

Comment: Então tira esses `{}` do `namespace`.

Comment: Bruno postei. Anderson vou fazer o teste sem as chaves .

Comment: Quando coloquei sem as chaves ele me retornou outro erro. Embora eu ainda ache que seja um erro relacionado ao namespace ou include, pois se eu dou um include em outra classe normal esse pacote funciona perfeitamente. O erro agora eh : ```<strong>Message:</strong> Constant FPDF_VERSION already defined```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma correta seria:

```
<?php namespace controllers; // Deve ser a primeira linha do arquivo e não se deve abrir chaves

include "fpdf/fpdf.php";

class Control {

    /*...*/

    public function PDF($romaneio) {
        // Classe está definida no escopo global, por isso se deve passar o \FPDF. Se tentar inicializar sem o \, é como se estivesse no escopo desse namespace, mas ela não está e por isso se deve chamar com \.
        $pdf =  new \FPDF("P", "pt", "A4");
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

> Obs.: Ocultei partes desnecessárias do código para demonstrar apenas onde deve corrigir. Faça a alteração e veja se vai funcionar. Caso queira chamar a classe `FPDF` apenas, em vez de `\FDPF`, você deve incluir no arquivo `fpdf/fpdf.php` no início do arquivo `namespace controllers;`.

Comment: Isso mesmo , ele localizou a classe, agora consigo manipular. Muito obrigado Bruno.

Comment: Estava com o comentário incorreto. Atualizei o texto, agora a explicação está correta e mais clara.